# How to design an template in Drools in order to pass list and map as an argument to generate the rules dynamically?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I have a list and an map in json format and before passing the those to template in order to generate the rules I convert them into the java and then compile them using the **ObjectDataCompiler** in order to generate the rules.

**JSON**

```
{
    "tags": [
          "ABC",
          "XYZ"
        ],
        "namedTags": {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2"
        },
        "type": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
   }
```

I have tried 2 methods to get the values in the **when** condition part of the rule while designing the template.

**1.** As it is mentioned in the example I found while the official docs as **tag[]**
link -->
https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#decision-examples-pricing-ref_drools-examples

**Template**

```
template header
tag[]
namedTags[]
type

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.example.template.FactNew;

template "list template"
rule "listone"
no-loop true
dialect "java"
when
         review:FactNew(
         "@{tag0}" == "XYZ"
         )
then
System.out.println("Setting the value for the list ");
modify(review){setName("NameList")}
end
end template
```

**Generated DRL** after compilation using the **objectDataCompiler**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.example.template.FactNew;

rule "listone"
no-loop true
dialect "java"
when
         review:FactNew(
         "[XYZ" == "XYZ"
         )
then
System.out.println("Setting the value for the list ");
modify(review){setCampaignNamePattern("NameList")}
end
```

Can you help as I am getting the this square brackets **"[","]"** appended to the first and last element respectively?
Same in case of the map I getting key and value along with these braces **"{","}"** respectively for first and last element.

**2.** Reading them as the other variables are read like string but that is not feasible as In order to validate them I need to write a function.

I would like to seek your assistance in order to understand the mistake I am doing and ho can I correct my mistake in order to implement list and map using the template in the drools correctly.

*P.S.-> Example will be really helpful;*

Comment: How are you converting the JSON into Java? Are you sure that the Java objects you get from the JSON don't contain already the wrong chars?

Comment: using the objectMapper.convertValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() and I am getting the proper values

Comment: Can you create a self-contained reproducer of this?